# Xcode Firebase authentication signs out everytime after closing the app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

So i have posted my loginviewcontroller code here.
Everything works fine but i would like to maintain user sessions after they close the app. The reason behind it so the user does not have to login every time when they open the app.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var Email: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Password: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var segmentlogin: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var Loiginbutton: UIButton!
    
    @IBAction func ActionLoginButoon(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
       
        if Email.text != "" && Password.text != ""
        {
            if segmentlogin.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 //Login user
            {
                Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: Email.text!, password: Password.text!) { (user, error) in
                    if user != nil
                    {
                    //Sign in Successful
                        //print("SUCCESS")
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segueone", sender: self)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if let myError = error?.localizedDescription
                            {
                            print(myError)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            print("ERROR") //Use Alert on Xcode look up how to
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        else //sign up user
            {
                Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: Email.text!, password: Password.text!) { (user, error) in
                if user != nil
                {
                    //Sign in Successful
                    //print("SUCCESS")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segueone", sender: self)
                    }
                else{
                    if let myError = error?.localizedDescription
                    {
                        print(myError)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("ERROR") //Use Alert on Xcode look up how to
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
        
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
//password can be just ... looking click on password box and secure text entry above control
```

Answer (score 1):

What this method does is
you first have a blank storyboard that decides if you have filled information in login view if you don't it will take you to log in view. once you fill that out you go back to blank storyboard to see if your login view filled. if it is filled you get pushed to the home view. if user deletes the app and downloads again that user will have to refill log in info otherwise the user will never have to refill it. let me know if you need to know how to logout.

You will need to create viewcontroller file using on the top left corner File->New->File->Cocoa Touch Class and save where your app is saved. name it AppContainerViewController

create another file using on the top left corner File->New->File->Swift File and save where your app is saved. name it AppManager

create new storyboard and connect it to AppContainerViewController (right side sotryboard under inspector->Custom Class-> class

In AppContainerViewController Type this code only

import UIKit

class AppContainerViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    AppManager.shared.appContainer = self
    AppManager.shared.showApp()

}
    

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

In AppManager type this code

import UIKit
import Firebase

class AppManager {

```
static let shared = AppManager()

let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var appContainer: AppContainerViewController!

private init() { }

func showApp(){

var viewController: UIViewController

if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
    viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") // login view where you sign in
} else {
    viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") // Homw view
    }
    
    appContainer.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}